# The method getFields() is undefined for the type JsonNode

Tags: java, jackson, jsonnode

I'm new to Java. I had to replace the reference to org.codehaus.jackson.JsonNode library with com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode to resolve security vulnerabilities. Now, I'm getting the above error.

```
private static String convertColumnsNamesToFieldNames(SFObjectModel model, JsonNode node,
        HashMap<String, String> aliasMap) {
    Iterator<Entry<String, JsonNode>> iter = node.getFields();
```

Do you know what the equivalent is in the new library?

I tried the fields() method and the error went away, but I really don't know if this is correct. Could someone confirm if this will work.

Comment: I suggest you compare the API . Not sure if these are what you are looking for: 
 https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html#fields()  https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/1.9/org/codehaus/jackson/JsonNode.html#getFields()

Comment: Consider adding `jsonnode` and `jackson` tags to your question. It will help more people familiar with those to find your question.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [`com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode.fields()`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html#fields())